# Object is possibly undefined, even with null checks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm working with Typescript 4.0.5 and getting an unsupressable

```
Object is possibly undefined
```

error

I have a piece of local state that contains a user uploaded .csv file

```
const [currentLine, setCurrentLine] = useState<File>();
```

my useEffect watches for the file change and parses the csv

```
  useEffect(
   () => {
   currentFile !== null && currentFile !== undefined  && currentFile.type === 'text/csv'
       ? Papa.parse(currentFile, {
           complete: (csv: File) => setParsedFile(csv)
         })
       : null;
   },
   [currentFile]
 );
```

Even with the null and undefined check, I'm still getting an error

```
 Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
```

I have tried wrapping the null/undefined checks in an if statement and get the same error, and have also tried using optional chaining with

```
currentFile?.type === 'text/csv'
```

This latter option seems to coerce currentFile to never and tells me that .type does not exist on never...

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here? We have a fairly messy package.json and I'm wondering if some tooling needs updating, as I can't see any reason for the errors here. for linting I'm on eslint 7.13.0, using eslint-config-prettier 6.15 for config.

Answer (score 1):

may be

```
  const [currentFile, setCurrentFile] = useState<File>(); 

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentFile && currentFile.type === 'text/csv')
      Papa.parse(currentFile, {
        complete: (csv: File) => setParsedFile(csv)
      });
    },
    [currentFile]
  );
```